# Создание собственного инструмента в Unity для 2D игры

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

Мне нужно сделать инструмент в Unity, с помощью которого я смогу делать 2D уровни.

Идея заключается в том, что инструмент будет напоминать режим edit mode коллайдера, то есть создавать и перемещать точки.

Затем из созданного пути я буду делать mash-рендер и полигон коллайдер, а внутри заполнять текстурой.

Как двигать и добавлять точки в редакторе, но при этом не создавать лишних объектов на сцене для этого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Меняете координаты точки - она двигается. Готово.

Comment: Все окажется немного сложнее чем кажется т.к. как минимум существуют еще развертки) Я бы в это не лез) ЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНО проще будет создавать все на основе наперед созданных ассетов-заготовок.

Comment: Редактор, генерация модели и триангуляция это ОЧЕНЬ большие темы не для начинающих, а уже на базовом уровне ты несешь полную окалесицу про "делать mash-рендер".